# Redirection loop (URL rewriting)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite my website URLs. I have:

> http:// website.com/v2/message.php?ID2=123

I want:

> http:// website.com/v2/message-123.php

I tried something in my htaccess but I've a redirection loop :'(

Here is my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ID2=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule message.php? http://website.com/v2/message-%1.php? [L,R=301]
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest not using `.php` in pretty URL, make it extension-less. Try these rules in `v2/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /v2/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /message\.php\?ID2=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ message-%1? [NE,R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^message-(.+)/?$ message.php?ID2=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```